# Create a DynamoDB GlobalSecondaryIndex to only include items with a specific attribute

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless, aws-serverless

I'm creating a DynamoDB table following the single table design principle.

My base table definition looks like this (serverless-framework):

```yaml
DataTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DATA_TABLE}
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: pk
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: sk
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: pk
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: sk
        KeyType: RANGE
```

Currently in the table are `Game` and `GamePlayer` objects, where a `Game` looks like this:

```json
{
    "pk": "GAME#game1", 
    "sk": "#META#game1", 
    "numPlayers": 2, 
    ... 
}
```

and a `GamePlayer` looks like this:

```json
{
    "pk": "GAME#game1", 
    "sk": "PLAYER#player1", 
    "score":10, 
    ... 
}
{
    "pk": "GAME#game1", 
    "sk": "PLAYER#player2", 
    "score":20, 
    ... 
}
```

I'd like to create an inverted index to search for games by player, so I update my table declaration to add a GlobalSecondaryIndex:

```yaml
DataTable:
  Type: AWS::DynamoDB::Table
  Properties:
    TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DATA_TABLE}
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: pk
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: sk
        AttributeType: S
    KeySchema:
      - AttributeName: pk
        KeyType: HASH
      - AttributeName: sk
        KeyType: RANGE
    GlobalSecondaryIndexes:
      - # for finding games by player
        IndexName: ${self:provider.environment.DATA_TABLE_PLAYER_GAME_INDEX}
        KeySchema:
          - AttributeName: sk
            KeyType: HASH
          - AttributeName: pk
            KeyType: RANGE
        Projection:
          NonKeyAttributes: 
            - score
          ProjectionType: "INCLUDE"
```

So basically `pk` and `sk` inverted, and I only want to project the keys, and the `score` property, which is all I'm interested in.

Looking at the index after the table is created, it's clear that Dynamo's included **ALL** the items from the base table, and copied over `score` on items where it exists.

If I set the `score` to be either the `HASH` or `RANGE` key, DynamoDB will only include that items with that attribute in the index.

Is there a way to have the same behaviour for a tertiary attribute, given that all items in this table will have a `pk` and an `sk` attribute, and thus will be included in the inverted index as well?

**Edit**

Apologies if the question isn't clear. I'll try to be more precise.

I'm developing a game using DynamoDB for the backend. I'm following the One Table design pattern as outlined here: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7VQs9L-G8O4

Basically, as you can have lots of different types of objects in the table, the partition key and sort key are generic, in this case `pk` and `sk`.

Currently, in my table I can store 3 types of objects: `Game`, `GamePlayer`, and `User`.

`Game` and `User`, as top-level objects follow the pattern where `pk` is a unique id and `sk` is just `#META#...` and their id. When a `User` joins a `Game`, I create a `GamePlayer`, where `pk` is the id of the game, and `sk` is `PLAYER#...` and the id of the `User`.

This lets me search for the `Game` and all the associated `GamePlayers` in one Query using `pk` as the id of the `Game` and `sk between #META and Player$` (see the video to get an idea of this if it's not clear).

As there are a lot of different objects in the table, there are obviously certain attributes that exist on one object but not on others - for example, an attribute `email` that would only exist on `User`, or `score` on `GamePlayer`.

One of the patterns mentioned in the video is the idea of an "inverted" index. As in, by default, with the id of a `Game`, I can get the `Game` and all `GamePlayers`. An inverted index is a GlobalSecondaryIndex with `sk` as the partition key and `pk` as the sort key. This would mean that, given the id of a `User`, I can now find all the `GamePlayer` objects associated with that `User`.

In order to not duplicate my entire DB, I only want to include the `score` property of `GamePlayer`, so I create my inverted index and set `score` as a `NonKeyAttribute` to be included. However, as *every* object in the DB includes the `pk` and `sk` attributes, Dynamo copies over every object, and sets the `score` property as `undefined` for the majority (as the attribute doesn't exist on those items).

If I wanted to create a GlobalSecondaryIndex for `Users`, for example, with `email` as either the partition or sort key, then Dynamo would only populate the index with `User` objects (i.e. there might be 5 items in the global table, but only 1 in the index).

So my question was, is it possible to keep my inverted index, but only include those items which have a `score` attribute?

Sample table:

| pk | sk | numPlayers | score | email |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| GAME#game1 | #META#game1 | 2 |  |  |
| GAME#game1 | PLAYER#player1 |  | 10 |  |
| GAME#game1 | PLAYER#player2 |  | 20 |  |
| USER#player1 | #META#player1 |  |  | me@email.com |

Comment: I have read this question several times and I still have no clue what it is you're asking. Maybe I'm just too dense, but could you tell us which query patterns and/or table layouts you want to see? Preferably with sample data in a nice table :-)

Comment: All items will be in the GSI. You can't change that behavior. Perhaps you could clarify your question.

Comment: If you are looking to only include rows in the GSI where there is a gameId attribute you'll need to change your GSI. You can either create columns just for the GSI (e.g. gsi1_pk, gsi1_sk) and populate them only when there is a value for the gameId, or you can include the gameId in the GSI partition.

Comment: @Maurice I've (hopefully) clarified the question :)

Comment: @JasonWadsworth it's looking more and more like something like `gs1_pk` being necessary, though it pains me to duplicate data unnecessarily. I can't include the `gameId` (or in the updated post, the `score`) in the GS1 partition, as I don't know it at the time of the search. Simple use case: a user disconnects - we need to find and notify all their current games

Comment: Duplicating data is pretty common in a NoSQL table. I wouldn't call the duplication "unnecessary". It is serving a purpose here.

Comment: @JasonWadsworth it looks like you're right; can you add your comment as an answer please, and I'll accept it